# Modifying autocomplete or copying vuetify style?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

so I'm pretty new to Vue.js and I wanted to modify the autocomplete component (basically make it give suggestions in the specific way that I want it to), which extends the select component. I was thinking to either make my own select component that uses the same style as the veautify select component, OR modifying the veautify autocomplete component to have my desired behavior. Is there a way to do either of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do either. You can use the `filter` property to determine the algorithm you want to use to return results:

> The filtering algorithm used when searching. [example](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete.ts#L36)

That lets you control how to search.

You can also control what is supplied back to the list by modifying the collection that is used for the `:items` property:

```
get items() {
   if (this.red && this.blue && this.shoe.hasOne() {
       return myCoolCollection.filter((item) => item.red && item.blue && item.shoe.count() === this.shoe.hasOne()
   }

   return myCoolCollection
}
```